# PHP how to json_encode() return from rrd_xport()?

Tags: php, arrays, json, rrd

I've recently run into an issue doing `json_encode(rrd_xport($options));` on RRD files generated by Nagios/Nagiosgraph.

`json_encode()` appears to fall over (thus returning FALSE) when `rrd_xport()` returns `NaN` as element values. For example (given $var = rrd_xport()'s return):

`print_r($var)` output:

```
Array
(
    [1418265300] =     297
    [1418265600] =     296.79333333333
    [1418265900] =     296.8
    [1418266200] =     295.79333333333
    [1418266500] =     295.40666666667
    [1418266800] =     296
    [1418267100] =     296
    [1418267400] =     296
    [1418267700] =     295.6
    [1418268000] =     296
    [1418268300] =     296.00666666667
    [1418268600] =     296.39333333333
    [1418268900] =     295.59333333333
    [1418269200] =     295.4
    [1418269500] =     295.79333333333
)
```

`json_encode($var)` output:

> {"1418263800":297,"1418264100":297.40666666667,"1418264400":297.39333333333,"1418264700":297,"1418265000":297,"1418265300":297,"1418265600":296.79333333333,"1418265900":296.8,"1418266200":295.79333333333,"1418266500":295.40666666667,"1418266800":296,"1418267100":296,"1418267400":296,"1418267700":295.6,"1418268000":296,"1418268300":296.00666666667,"1418268600":296.39333333333,"1418268900":295.59333333333,"1418269200":295.4,"1418269500":295.79333333333}

Now, when we (rrd_xport) introduce a `NaN` to an element value, we see `json_encode()` spew:

NEW `print_r($var)` output:

```
Array
(
    [1418265300] =     297
    [1418265600] =     296.79333333333
    [1418265900] =     296.8
    [1418266200] =     295.79333333333
    [1418266500] =     295.40666666667
    [1418266800] =     296
    [1418267100] =     296
    [1418267400] =     296
    [1418267700] =     295.6
    [1418268000] =     296
    [1418268300] =     296.00666666667
    [1418268600] =     296.39333333333
    [1418268900] =     295.59333333333
    [1418269200] =     295.4
    [1418269500] =     295.79333333333
    [1418269800] =     NAN
)
```

`var_dump(json_encode($var))` output:

> bool(false)

Finally, my question: What's the nicest way to deal with this - do we need to trawl the entire array and replace `NaN`? (The real output is far bigger than this example, and multidimensional) Surely there's a better way!

Comment: can you var_dump $var? what is `NAN` type? is it string?

Comment: var_dump($var) tells me rrd_xport made all values a float() in this case (including NAN values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) Specification has not anything about how to encode `NaN` or `Inf` entities:

```
Numeric values that cannot be represented as sequences of digits (such as Infinity and NaN) are not permitted.
```

You should iterate through and replace `is_nan($v)` values to anything applicable with `JSON`, for example to null...

Or you can implement your own `js_encode` function

Answer (score 1):

**Wound up looping through the array, thanks vp_arth!**

```
function killnan($maybeHasNan)
{
        if (gettype($maybeHasNan) != "array")
        {
                echo "AHSHIT\n";
                return;
        }

        $iMakedThis = Array();

        foreach ($maybeHasNan as $key =     $value)
        {
                if (gettype($value) == "array")
                {
                        # go deeper neo
                        $iMakedThis[$key] = killnan($value);
                }

                elseif (gettype($value) == "double" && is_nan($value))
                {
                        $iMakedThis[$key] = NULL;
                }

                else
                {
                        $iMakedThis[$key] = $value;
                }
        }

        return $iMakedThis;
}
```